# Debian 7 DNS iptables

Tags: linux, dns, iptables

I've set up a small web server on a debian 7 machine, and added a firewall so that it works. Here are the rules.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Stopping firewall and allowing everyone..."
ipt="/sbin/iptables"
## Failsafe - die if /sbin/iptables not found 
[ ! -x "$ipt" ] && { echo "$0: \"${ipt}\" command not found."; exit 1; }

$ipt -P INPUT ACCEPT
$ipt -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$ipt -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$ipt -F
$ipt -X
$ipt -t nat -F
$ipt -t nat -X
$ipt -t mangle -F
$ipt -t mangle -X
$ipt -t raw -F
$ipt -t raw -X

echo "Adding rules so that only SFTP,SSH,HTTP and DNS are allowed..."
$ipt -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 21,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
$ipt -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -j DROP

$ipt -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -o lo -p all -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -j DROP

$ipt -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

This works well for SFTP,SSH,HTTP and HTTPS. Any idea why DNS not working? I've tried many more complex solutions on the web but none working...

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1024:65535 -d 213.186.33.99 --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo echo -n "hi" > /dev/udp/213.186.33.99/53
echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: what exactly is creating that `/dev/udp` tree? that doesn't exist on my ubuntu box.

Comment: I think bash is creating the tree as I read over the internet but I must say not quite sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your rule is fine:

```
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 1024:65535 -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 55 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 55 -j DROP
# iptables -nL OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:55 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:55
# nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 55
hi
^C
# iptables -vnL OUTPUT 
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 169 packets, 63116 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    31 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:55 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DROP       udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:55
```

Try your test again with netcat, `nc(1)`, instead of bash.

Comment: Not working either on my side. Actually I can easily tell if a solution is working because my goal is to enable DNS, and ping google.com fails

Comment: Can you get it to work with 127.0.0.1 like I demonstrated?

Comment: Yes, the rule allow everything from loopback allows it to work, but it's not that rule that makes it work

Comment: Maybe the problem is at an intervening network node.  Do you have another box on the same network you can send the packets to, to see if they arrive?  Does tcpdump show the packets leaving and/or arriving?

Comment: Nope, doesn't show any DNS related output. I know it's a iptables issue, since if I remove all firewall rules, this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved using

```
$ipt -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport --dports 21,22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
$ipt -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -i lo -p all -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A INPUT -j DROP

$ipt -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -o lo -p all -j ACCEPT
$ipt -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

Don't know why, but eh, thanks anyways